# Can schannel be used to make a ssl connection to a webserver like nginx

Tags: c++, https, webserver, winsock2, schannel

I am wanting to use schannel to make an ssl or tls connection to a webserver running https, preferably nginx. I have an nginx instance running right now, and am successfully sending http get requests via winsock to the server. Now I am wanting to secure this with schannel.

I have read that schannel is the way to go for a windows client and server, but what if the server isn't IIS and is running on linux. Is this possible? I am aware there are other libraries that can be used in c++, but I specifically want to use schannel. All of the code examples related to schannel seem to have a windows server, which is casting doubt in my mind about it being a possibility.

Comment: Yes, SChannel will work (but it is [quite complex to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/creating-a-secure-connection-using-schannel)). It doesn't matter what software the server is running, SSL/TLS is the same protocol regardless of implementation, and SChannel can talk SSL/TLS. However, that being said, why do you want to implement HTTPS manually, instead of using the WinInet/WinHTTP API?

Comment: Remy Lebeau, it was requested of me, I'm constrained by it unfortunately. I assume the requester has a good reason.